# "Enter 2-step verification code"

Tags: google-fabric

For some reason, after entering the 6-digit confirmation code, I'm asked to "Enter 2-step verification code". Does anyone know why another code is needed? I don't quite recall setting up another code though.

Any thought appreciated.

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. If you're being asked to enter a second code it means at some point 2FA was set up for Digits for your number. Email support(at)fabric(dot)io with your number and we can do a reset.

Comment: @MikeBonnell Hi Mike. How is 2FA setup? There's a chance I did accidentally set it up.

Comment: It's setup via get.digits.com under Account.